# How to Jquery get value SmoothZoom

Tags: jquery, canvas, zooming

I buy script 
[Click here](http://www.beger.co.th/colordesign/zoom/)
Original can **getdataZoom** and Click any buttom can
when i input to my project have problem cannot get data Zoom

[Click Here](http://www.beger.co.th/colordesign/?mod=ad-image&f=1389089623.jpg&MJid=174&cid=174&p=174.aki)

```
function writeObject(){
var zoomDataObject = $('#dataweb').smoothZoom('getZoomData');   


}
```

`zoomDataObject :` no data when i request it

Answer (score 0):

The function you are showing us does nothing.  You make the `zoomDataObject` but then don't do anything with it.  The function in the [Original Source](http://www.beger.co.th/colordesign/zoom/) that you linked has this version of that function:

```
function writeObject(){

        var zoomDataObject = $('#yourImageID').smoothZoom('getZoomData');       
        $('#code').html(        
            "Normal X: <span style='color:#000000'>"+parseInt(zoomDataObject.normX) +"</span>"
            +"<br />Normal Y: <span style='color:#000000'>"+parseInt(zoomDataObject.normY) +"</span>"
            +"<br />Normal Width: <span style='color:#000000'>"+parseInt(zoomDataObject.normWidth) +"</span>"
            +"<br />Normal Height: <span style='color:#000000'>"+parseInt(zoomDataObject.normHeight) +"</span>"

            +"<br /><br />Scaled X: <span style='color:#000000'>"+parseInt(zoomDataObject.scaledX)  +"</span>"
            +"<br />Scaled Y: <span style='color:#000000'>"+parseInt(zoomDataObject.scaledY) +"</span>"
            +"<br />Scaled Width: <span style='color:#000000'>"+parseInt(zoomDataObject.scaledWidth) +"</span>"
            +"<br />Scaled Height: <span style='color:#000000'>"+parseInt(zoomDataObject.scaledHeight) +"</span>"

            +"<br /><br />Center X: <span style='color:#000000'>"+parseInt(zoomDataObject.centerX) +"</span>"
            +"<br />Center Y: <span style='color:#000000'>"+parseInt(zoomDataObject.centerY) +"</span>" 

            +"<br /><br />Scale Ratio:<br /> <span style='color:#000000'>"+zoomDataObject.ratio +"</span>"      
        );  
    }
```

Comment: I try to do this case but i get data some function

Comment: $('#dataweb').smoothZoom({
   width: '100%',
   height: '100%',
   zoom_MAX: 150,
   zoom_SINGLE_STEP:false,
   initial_ZOOM:"",
   zoom_OUT_TO_FIT:true,
   border_TRANSPARENCY: 20,
            touch_DRAG:false,
            mouse_DRAG:false,
   mouse_DOUBLE_CLICK:false,
   responsive: false,
   responsive_maintain_ratio: false,
   mouse_WHEEL:true,
   mouse_WHEEL_CURSOR_POS:true,
   max_WIDTH: '',
   max_HEIGHT: ''
  });

Comment: work at zoom but not work with get data i think object i working try to get data raio and anything from this